# How do you create a Developer account for DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am brand new to using the DocuSign API.  My company has issued me a DocuSign account and I believe I am set up as a developer.  Going through the introductory documentation, I see it says to create or log into a dev sandbox.

I've tried the following:

1. Log into demo.docusign.net with my existing work account. This fails saying there is no such account, though I can log into that account on www.docusign.net.
2. Log into demo.docusign.net with a newly-created personal account. This fails saying there is no such account, though I can log into that account on www.docusign.net.
3. Select "Sign up" on demo.docusign.net. This brings me to a new-account page. I can create an account there which works with www.docusign.net, but not on demo.docusign.net.
4. Log in to demo.docusign.net using my Google account.  That fails with the error "Social ID is not linked to a DocuSign membership."

So, what do I do?  My goal is to set up a sandbox, ideally with my work account, where I can experiment and debug without affecting production data. How do I set up such a sandbox?

Or, am I on a completely wrong track? Do I not need such a sandbox to do development?

Comment: Sandbox accounts are completely separate from your production account. Here is the sign up link: https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer

Comment: Andrew, please re-do your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandbox accounts are completely separate from your production account.

Here is the sign up link: https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer